# How to use importmap(rails) in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning rails, I am working on windows 10, I have installed importmap and according to the documentation I can install js libraries however it doesnt work at all this way

```
bin/importmap pin jquery
```

I have tried:

```
rails importmap pin jquery
```

and I get:

```
Don't know how to build task 'importmap' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
```

How could I install js libraries in rails propertly by using importmap

Thnks for your help

Answer (score 3):

from the project directory commandline:

```
>ruby bin\importmap pin jquery
```

Comment: That's a very good solution. I've resorted to using WSL but this is much easyer!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is such a problem. There is no dependence on the operating system.

But it is not clear from your question whether you included importmap in an old project or created a new project.

The sequence of actions in which I bypass (I work on linux) this problem:

```
mkdir new_rails_project && cd new_rails_project
echo "source 'https://rubygems.org'" > Gemfile
echo "gem 'rails', '7.0.4'" >> Gemfile
bundle install
bundle exec rails new . --force  # --css=bootstrap -d=postgresql if necessary, etc.
```

Result:

```
./bin/importmap pin jquery
Pinning "jquery" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.1/dist/jquery.js
```